# Calculation of heat generated by a battery pack

Tags: power-dissipation

I have to calculate the heat generated by a 40 cell battery. The max. voltage is 4.2 V, nominal voltage is 3.7 V and the cell capacity is 1.5 Ah, discharging at a rate of 2 C.

If I calculate the heat generated according to $$Q = P \times t = V \times I \times t = 4.2\text{ V} \times 3\text{ A} \times 30/60\text{ h} = 6.3\text{ W in }1\text{ hour or }3.15\text{ W in }30\text{ minutes}$$

But according to "Analysis of Cooling Effectiveness and Temperature Uniformity in a Battery Pack for Cylindrical Batteries" by Seham Shahid * and Martin Agelin-Chaab, the power dissipated is 3.7W. How is it possible?

Comment: What you have calculated is the power dissipated in the **load**, not in the battery itself. Please provide a link to the manufacturer's datasheet for the battery as well as a link to the paper you mention.

Comment: "*... = 6.3W **in** 1 hour*". No, it's 6.3 W **for** 1 hour = 6.3 Wh = 6.3 x 3600 Ws = 6.3 x 3600 J. Multiplying power by time gives you the **energy** but you haven't been asked for that - just the power.

Comment: I can't see where the internal resistance of the cells in the battery appears in the calculations. Could you edit the question to show that?

Answer (score 1):

This paper seems flawed in that the assumptions of battery capacity matching and the ESR values were never mentioned.  Although a complex analysis with Reynolds numbers and heat thermographs of different cooling methods were discussed.  There was no mention of heat power released (Watts) from losses or thermal resistance in 'C/W rise.  Instead, they measured heat flux with sensors in a thermally insulated experiment.

They use 32 Samsung cells with [these specs](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Specifications-of-the-test-cell-Samsung-INR-18650-25R-14_tbl1_341219370) and tested with 5A discharge (2C) and indicated based on heat flux tests "the average value of 2.75 W of the heat generation rate was used."

You can compute the average ESR not from Pout=VI, but from \$P=I^2R\$.
In any case for a typical 18650, Li Ion I estimate  battery ESR between 50 and 100 mOhms.

Their results were \$ESR=\dfrac{P_{loss}}{I^2} = \dfrac{2.75}{5^2}= 110 ~mohm \$

It might have been more succinct if they reported the improvement in Rth, thermal resistance for different cooling methods of battery packs.

From my experience in thermal design, it is not the linear air velocity that counts, rather the peak surface velocity with amplified velocity from turbulent eddy currents of a vortex air flow.

Answer (score 0):

The number on the paper has a different meaning than Q.

Heat is generated from other than effective power. Effective power is used to drive the load. Thus, "4.2V * 3A * 30/60h" is a straight calculation of (though need some more considerations) power we are drawing from the battery, but not the power to generate heat. Heat is generated from "inefficiency", offset to an ideal power source. I would say the main source of heat is the chemical reaction and loading on internal impedance. These are very much studied. Battery manufactures and pack manufactures try to answer by experiments, and establish mathmatics/algorithmic formulas. The paper is showing measured heat, dissipated from the battery with various conditions.

Comment: Small but important correction: "*Thus, "4.2V * 3A * 30/60h" is a straight calculation of (though need some more considerations) **power** we are drawing from the battery.*" V x A x t = P x t = **energy** drawn, not power.